# How to DIY terminate Multimode Fiber?

Tags: fiber

I wired my house using a Honeywell Genesis series multimedia cable (part no. [5956](https://www.honeywellcable.com/CatalogDocuments/5956.pdf)) Among four other cables, it also has (2) 62.5um multimode fibers bundled together in a cable. (Those two 62.5/125 MMF are surrounded by Kevlar under PVC jacket.)

Following is the optical characteristic of the fiber optic cable:

```
Core/Clad | Typ. Atten. | Max Atten. | Min LED Bandwidth
          |  (dB/km)    |  (dB/km)   |     (Mhz*km)
--------------------------------------------------------
62.5/125  |  3.0 / 1.0  | 3.75 / 1.5 |    160 / 500
```

I am finishing the network wiring now, and I have all the tools and knowledge to terminate all RG6 and Ethernet connections in my Keystone wall plates for the other four cables, but I don't know what I need in order to terminate that fiber optic cable in a keystone wall plate.

Any guidance or DIY tutorial available for that?

Comment: That's some seriously antiquated fiber.

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations and questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su]. You will need some expensive tools like a fiber microscope and polisher, and the fiber modules for your very expensive (~$10,000) cable tester that you already have for your RG6 and UTP cabling.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is probably to forget it exists and move on. That fiber is so obsolete it's like not having fiber at all. The fact that that type of fiber is packaged in the same cable as Cat6 wire bespeaks shady marketing, at the kindest view - outright scam comes to mind as well.

If you want to teach yourself to DIY fiber connections and are willing to invest several hundred dollars to connectorize your obsolete fiber, it's quite do-able. Or you can spend similar money to have someone else come do it for you.

The usual recommendation for home-scale termination is mechanical splice connectors. It's not my recommendation, but it is the usual one.

Epoxy-polish connectors are what I taught myself to do (I had a campus to do, not a house, and the fiber was not pre-obsolete) and with careful shopping I think it set me back about $400 to be completely equipped for the job. Fiber stripper, scribe, polishing puck, oven, epoxy, epoxy syringes, polishing pad, polishing media, fiber scope, fiber scrap container, work mat. You can easily spend a lot more. You can skip the oven if you use a different type of epoxy and can leave the fibers undisturbed for a long time.

Fusion-splice connectors are good and easy, but require a fusion-splicer, which is very expensive, and the splice-on connectors are also expensive compared to epoxy-polish.

Answer (score 1):

You could either fusion-splice pigtails onto the ends or fit and polish user-installable ferrules but both methods require training and specialized equipment and are not suited for DIY.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, there may be another problem: 62.5 µm MMF is from the FDDI era and has little reach with modern PHYs (33 m for 10GBASE-SR).